# Shortest path crossing unique x points

Tags: algorithm, path, distance, shortest

Given a set of Y Points (locations) with Longitude and Latitude, what is the shortest path that crosses a Unique set of X points?

Just a algorithm problem I was having when designing a database. Not sure how to proceed or if there is an elegant solution to this problem. Please help! Thanks!

Edit: This is not the Travelling Salesmen Problem, it is not the shortest path visiting ALL the locations, but just any unique set that crosses X points.

For example, if we had 2000 locations, what's the shortest path that will visit any 10 locations?

The size of X will be very small compared to the overall set of Y.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Actually, it's not the same problem, it does not visit all locations, except only X of them

Comment: You mean ANY 10 locations (the algorithm can pick them)?

Comment: correct, any 10 locations

Comment: And, I know there has to be a better solution than just combinations of the traveling salesmen problem.

Comment: how big is your graph? sparse/dense? how long are the desired path? are you looking for approximations?

Comment: I strongly suspect that this would be considered as just a variant of the TSP problem.

Comment: if size of X is asymptotically equal to the size of Y, then it is TSP.

Comment: size of X is not asymptotically equal to size of Y. Y is MUCH larger than X. We are dealing with dense graphs. Looking for best approximation.

Comment: off the top of my head... metric TSP has a fairly simple 1.5 [approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm). Also, there should be approximations with up to (1+eps) precision for general TSPs. However, if |X| is small (e.g. < 10), I'd personally go with brute-force search + pruning/heuristics. Iterative deepening DFS, Bellman-Ford, etc.

Comment: This is definitely the traveling salesman problem, unless you mean that the path to X points must travel through Y points instead of directly, in which case the solution would obviously be more complex than the TSP. I can create a TSP with one hundred points, then remove 50 of them, but I still have a traveling salesman problem.

Comment: It's not TSP, it's more like a variant of the elevator dispatching problem where Y people are waiting in the lobby, you need to get X to their destinations in one trip, and the elevator moves in 2-D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put my data into an [R* Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%2a_tree) then run a [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) algorithm over it to break it down into clusters O(n * lg(n)). Once the points have been clustered you can then find the cluster that's closest in size to the number of points you want to find the shortest path between. Since you've broken everything down to just 10 points you have two options you can either: Solve the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) for the points which is slow O(n!) and precise, or take the leftmost point and get the shortest path to the rightmost point using [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) which is much faster O(E + V * log(V)) but doesn't give you the optimal result.

**EDIT!**

As pointed out in the comments below using Dijkstra's algorithm here would result in O(n!+V * log(V)) since any path between two points is an edge. It would be faster to use the Held–Karp algorithm to solve the TSP which runs O(n^2 * 2^n)

Comment: `E` is order `n!` here, or we could run Dijkstra's to solve the TSP

Comment: Nice catch that's my bad. Looks like it would just be better to use Held-Karp's Algorithm for solving TSP in O(n^2 * 2^n) with either case.

Comment: Well, we have both made atrocious errors. obviously the number of edges  is `n*(n-1)/2`. There is a good reason you can't use Dijksta's shortest path algorithm to do a TSP though, namely the shortest path does not traverse the points.